# Save Multiple featured product info into MySQL in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have attached my problems in jpg file for the issues of code format:::

Problem is that it's not saving any data into the "tbl_featured_table".

## Controller

```
public function save_featured_product() {
$data = array();

if ($this->input->post()) {
$data['featured_id'] = $this->input->post('featured_id', true);
$data['product_id'] = $this->input->post('product_id', true);
$data['product_name'] = $this->input->post('product_name', true);

$data['featured_product_name'] = $this->input->post('featured_product_name', true);
$data['featured_product_price'] = $this->input->post('featured_product_price', true);
$data['featured_product_quantity'] = $this->input->post('featured_product_quantity', true);
$data['featured_product_sku'] = $this->input->post('featured_product_sku', true);
$data['featured_product_short_description'] = $this->input->post('featured_product_short_description', true);
$data['featured_product_long_description'] = $this->input->post('featured_product_long_description', true);
$data['featured_product_status'] = $this->input->post('featured_product_status', true);
$data['featured_product_image'] = $this->input->post('featured_product_image', true);

$this->sa_model->save_featured_product_info($data);
}
```

## Model

```
function save_featured_product_info($data){
if (isset($data['product_id']) && is_array($data['product_id'])) {
foreach ($data['product_id'] as $key => $each) {
$temp[] = array(
'featured_id' => $data['featured_id'][$key],
'product_id' => $data['product_id'][$key],
'product_name' => $data['product_name'][$key],
'featured_product_name' => $data['featured_product_name'][$key],
'featured_product_price' => $data['featured_product_price'][$key],
'featured_product_quantity' => $data['featured_product_quantity'][$key],
'featured_product_sku' => $data['featured_product_sku'][$key],
'featured_product_short_description' => $data['featured_product_short_description'][$key],
'featured_product_long_description' => $data['featured_product_long_description'][$key],
'featured_product_status' => $data['featured_product_status'][$key],
'featured_product_image' => $data['featured_product_image'][$key],
);
}
if (isset($temp)) {
$this->db->insert_batch('tbl_featured_products', $temp);
}
```

## view

```
        Product Name:
    <select name="product_id[]">
    <?php foreach ($all_product as $values) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $values->product_name; ?>"><?php echo $values->product_name; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php foreach ($all_product as $values) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="featured_product_name[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_name; ?>" /> 
    <?php echo $values->product_name; ?> <br>
    <input hidden="hidden" name="featured_id[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_id; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_name; ?>" >
    <input name="featured_product_price[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_price;?>" /> 
    <input name="featured_product_quantity[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_quantity; ?>" /> 
    <input name="featured_product_sku[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_sku; ?>" /> 
    <input name="featured_product_short_description[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_short_description; ?>" /> 
    <input name="featured_product_long_description[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_long_description; ?>" /> 
    <input name="featured_product_status[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_status; ?>" /> 
    <input name="featured_product_image[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_image; ?>" /> 
    <?php } ?>
```

Note That ::: I would like to save multiple data by product name or product id. It is not working as well. I need your help to solve my problems.

Please help me by professionally. Please do not rating me in Negative.

Comment: Post your model code here

Comment: I have included the model code in the middle area.. Please have a look:::

"Model" can't be post here ... it has too much character (stackoverflow)

Comment: No post your code. Not possible to write the whole code myself. This is not a good way of posting questions.

Comment: add this code to the answer, its hard to read..

Comment: Post your view too. you can remove the image if you would like.

Comment: Posted the view codes. Please do not rating me in Negative. help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**View**:

```
<select name="product_id[]">
<?php foreach ($all_product as $values) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $values->product_name; ?>"><?php echo $values->product_name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<?php foreach ($all_product as $values) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="product_id[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_id; ?>" /> 
<?php echo $values->product_name; ?> <br />
<!-- <input hidden="hidden" name="featured_id[]" value="<?php //echo $values->product_id; ?>" /> -->
<input type="hidden" name="product_name[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_name; ?>" />
<input name="featured_product_price[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_price;?>" /> 
<input name="featured_product_quantity[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_quantity; ?>" /> 
<input name="featured_product_sku[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_sku; ?>" /> 
<input name="featured_product_short_description[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_short_description; ?>" /> 
<input name="featured_product_long_description[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_long_description; ?>" /> 
<input name="featured_product_status[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_status; ?>" /> 
<input name="featured_product_image[]" value="<?php echo $values->product_image; ?>" />
```

**Controller**

```
function save_featured_product() {
    $data = array();
    $feat = array();
    $fin  = array();
    if ($this->input->post()) {
        $feat    = $this->input->post('product_id', true);
        $data['featured_id']                        = $this->input->post('featured_id', true);
        //$data['product_id']                         = $this->input->post('product_id', true);
        $data['product_name']                       = $this->input->post('product_name', true);
        //$data['featured_product_name']              = $this->input->post('featured_product_name', true);
        $data['featured_product_price']             = $this->input->post('featured_product_price', true);
        $data['featured_product_quantity']          = $this->input->post('featured_product_quantity', true);
        $data['featured_product_sku']               = $this->input->post('featured_product_sku', true);
        $data['featured_product_short_description'] = $this->input->post('featured_product_short_description', true);
        $data['featured_product_long_description']  = $this->input->post('featured_product_long_description', true);
        $data['featured_product_status']            = $this->input->post('featured_product_status', true);
        $data['featured_product_image']             = $this->input->post('featured_product_image', true);
       if( isset( $feat ) && is_array( $feat ) && count( $feat ) > 0 ){
            foreach( $feat as $key => $each ){
                $fin[]  = array(
                'product_id'                            => $each,
                'product_name'                          => $data['product_name'][$key],
                'featured_product_price'                => $data['featured_product_price'][$key],
                'featured_product_quantity'             => $data['featured_product_quantity'][$key],
                'featured_product_sku'                  => $data['featured_product_sku'][$key],
                'featured_product_short_description'    => $data['featured_product_short_description'][$key],
                'featured_product_long_description'     => $data['featured_product_long_description'][$key],
                'featured_product_status'               => $data['featured_product_status'][$key],
                'featured_product_image'                => $data['featured_product_image'][$key],
                );  
            }
       } 
    $this->sa_model->save_featured_product_info($fin);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function save_featured_product_info($data){
    if( is_array( $data ) && count( $data ) > 0 ){
        $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_featured_products', $data);    
    }
}
```

Comment: changed the code then it shows "Error Number: 1048

Column 'product_name' cannot be null"

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It is working for only one row. I want to add multiple featured product by product.

Comment: :: I want to save multiple checkbox according to a product name or ID ... Please help me out.

Comment: Hope it works, Atleast you will get a fair example of how to do it.

Comment: i would do this very differently but am upvoting you because of the massive work you put in, so cheers.

Comment: @ cartalot ::: This is great... It's saving data in multiple row. BUT it is not working Perfectly. 1. It saved all product_name and product_id from <select> <option>. 2. Product_id starts from 0.

:::: Please fix them 2

Comment: what problem you are facing here now? clarify @SelimReza

Answer (score 1):

i'm just going to give you some general tips. And kudos for including the xss clean TRUE in your $this->input->post

Always start a project like this with just one or two values. get it to work. then add the rest of your fields. i call this a 'sanity check' because trying to deal with this many fields -- will drive you crazy :-)

Look at the code in your controller. Now look at the code in your model. Do you see how you have a lot of code - for exactly the same values? **Controllers should be thin and bossy.** Controllers boss like this: Did this form Validate true or false? If false - show the view again. If true: Did you add the values to the database table yes or no? If yes - show a success page.

**The models do the heavy lifting of data.** The model validates the form data. the model creates the data array needed for the database. for something that has this much data - create a separate method that just creates the data array. then you have a nice simple database call like

```
function _insertProduct( $product ) {
    $this->db->insert( 'tbl_featured_products', $product );
    if ( $this->db->affected_rows() == '1' ) {return TRUE;}
    else {return FALSE;}

}
```

look at that simple beautiful code. and it lets us know whether the insert worked or not.

now look at this from your model db method

```
if (isset($data['product_id']) && is_array($data['product_id'])) {
```

NO NO NO! and no! **if you pass a data structure to a database call - you have cleaned and polished and waxed it first.** you know its perfect and valid, so you don't have to second guess yourself with a bunch of confusing is this set?

finally never ever ever name anything: temp 
because what does temp mean? answer: it doesn't mean anything. and thats a problem. and while i'm ranting don't call it $data. **reserve the name $data only for values you are passing to the view.** (Ok i know that one might not be a popular opinion but i promise it will make your coding easier). method and variable names are really important, they are your guideposts through your code journey :-)

Comment: thank you so much. I am going to follow your instruction. I will let you know the update. I am so much happy with your explanation. I really like this. Thanks again

Comment: It is not working. it shows database error :::
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: product

Filename: controllers/super_admin.php

Line Number: 235
 :::::::::::::::: 
A Database Error Occurred

You must use the "set" method to update an entry.

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\shop\system\database\DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 1174

Comment: If you are trying to modify or change an existing database record - that is an UPDATE. if you are creating a completely new database record - that is an INSERT. the two are very different from each other.

Comment: After getting data from one table then want to insert multiple data by checkbox in another table